# Python: Checking if a Linux alias exists

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I am having difficulty finding online if there is a way to check in Python 3.x if an alias exists in Linux.

Ex. A Python script is launched and it creates an alias on first run to make it easier to be run the next time. To avoid making an alias on every run, it would check if it already exists, and if True, move to the next script.

Comment: `alias` is a shell concept. Look at `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True`.

Comment: How does it create the alias, by editing the user's `.bashrc`? Then it can read the `.bashrc` and see if the alias line is already in there.